# Sequence $(x_n)$ whose first $p$ terms is a complete residue system: value of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{n}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\{x_{n}\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{N}$ with $x_{1}=1$ such that for any prime $p$, the set $$A=\{x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{p}\}$$ forms a complete residue system $\pmod{p}$. Now is it true that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n}}{n}$ exists? If yes what is it's value?

Comment: What do you mean by the question whether that limit "exists for any natural number $n$"?

Comment: @JulesLamers Edited. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I guess (after checking until 7) that $(x_n)$ has to be the identity, up to permutations of values between primes (e.g., 1,2,3,5,4,7,6,8,9, etc). I guess it's provable elementarily. Since the gap around a prime $p$ is $\ll p$, this would imply that indeed $x_n/n$ tends to 1, since $x_n$ would then belong to $[u(n)+1,n]$, where $u(n)$ is the largest prime $<n$.

Comment: @YCor How did you check till 7??

Comment: @YCor More permutations than just those of values between primes (which I take to mean: permutations in $S_2\times S_{3-2}\times S_{5-3}\times S_{7-5}\times S_{11-7}\times \cdots$) are possible: e.g. 3,2,1,4,5,... is such a sequence too.

Comment: @JulesLamers 3,2,1 does not work because $x_1=1$ by definition.

Comment: @crskhr first $x_2$: $x_2$ has to be even, and $x_2-x_1$ should not be divisible by any prime. So $x_2=2$ (assuming the convention $0\notin\mathbb{N}$). Then $x_3$ should be such that $x_3-x_i$ is not divisible by any prime $\ge 3$ for $i=1,2$. This means that $x_3-1$ and $x_3-2$ are both powers of 2, hence these are $2,1$ and $x_3=3$. Then for $j=4,5$, and $i=1,2,3$, $x_j-x_i=x_j-i$ is not divisible by any prime $\ge 5$, i.e. has the form $2^n3^m$. We need 3 consecutive such numbers: the only possibilities are 1,2,3 and 2,3,4, so $x_j\in\{4,5\}$, and we deduce $\{x_4,x_5\}=\{4,5\}$. etc...

Comment: Btw assuming $0\in\mathbb{N}$ does not matter: if we make $x_1$ arbitrary and allow elements of $\mathbb{Z}$, the solutions are $(ex_n+k)$, where $(x_n)$ is a positive solution (as in the original question) with $x_1=1$, $k\in\mathbf{Z}$ and $e\in\{\pm 1\}$. So assuming $(x_n)$ bounded below forces $e=1$ and $x_n\ge x_1$ for all $n$. (More simply: if $x_1=1$ and $x_2=0$,  we easily obtain $x_3=-1$.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This problem is due to Imre Ruzsa who posed it at the 2015 Miklós Schweitzer Contest in Hungary: https://mathproblems123.wordpress.com/2015/10/31/miklos-schweitzer-2015-problems/

Here is a solution (thanks also to YCor for his comments and encouragement). It is easy to see that $x_1=1$ and $x_2=2$. We claim that $\{x_1,\dots,x_p\}$ equals $\{1,\dots,p\}$ for every prime $p$. Let us assume that this holds for some prime $p$, and let us show that it also holds for the next prime $q$ in place of $p$. For this, it suffices to verify that $x_j\leq q$ holds for any $p<j\leq q$. By assumption, the $p$ consecutive positive integers $x_j-p,\dots,x_j-1$ are not divisible by $q$ or by any larger prime. Hence trivially $x_j\not\in\{q+1,\dots,q+p\}$, but rather nontrivially also $x_j\leq 2p$ by the [Sylvester-Schur theorem](https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1934-01.pdf). As $2p<q+p$, these two relations force that $x_j\leq q$, and we proved the claim. In particular, if $n$ is a positive integer, and $p<n\leq q$ for the consecutive primes $p<q$, then $p/q<x_n/n<q/p$. This implies that $x_n/n\to 1$, because the ratio of consecutive primes tends to $1$ by the prime number theorem.

Comment: Thanks. For the kind help.  It would be nice if anyone can elaborate more on the ideas :)

Comment: Great, it seems that indeed the Sylvester-Schur theorem exactly does the job. Namely it says (for those who don't want to open the link) that for all $n>k\ge 1$, the set of integers $\{n,n+1,\dots,n+k-1\}$ contains a number with a prime divisor $>k$.

Comment: @YCor: Thank you. See my "Added" section.

Comment: That was a nice problem.  Is there a convenient place to find all the Schweitzer competition problems?  Ah: Google works:  http://www.math.u-szeged.hu/~mmaroti/schweitzer/ ; and Art of Problem Solving has them in English.

Comment: @Lucia: Yes, Ruzsa is a genius. For the Schweitzer contest problems between 1962 and 1991 there is the book http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387945880. Actually, I remember attending a public lecture by Paul Erdős (around 1993 at Eötvös Loránd University) where he stressed the importance of publishing such a book.

Comment: @YCor: Note also that, by the work of Baker-Harman-Pintz, we have $p/q=1+O(p^{-19/40})$, hence $x_n/n=1+O(n^{-19/40})$ as well.

Comment: @GHfromMO: Is Hungarian your Muttersprache?